# java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Main, method: main signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V) Stack size too large

Tags: java, assembly, jython, java-bytecode-asm

I've been looking into the ASM library.  First I wrote a program to build a hello world class and then I thought I'd try something a little more involved,  build a class that creates a PythonInterpreter(part of the the Jython library) and executes a python file.  The result is the following, unfortunately I get the exception I named this question after when I try to execute the resulting class.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mainFile = "main.py";

    ClassWriter mainClass = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
    mainClass.visit(Opcodes.V1_5, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "Main", null, "java/lang/Object", null);
    MethodVisitor mainMethod = mainClass.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V", null, null);

    mainMethod.visitTypeInsn(Opcodes.NEW, "org/python/util/PythonInterpreter");
    mainMethod.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "org/python/util/PythonInterpreter", "<init>", "()V");

    mainMethod.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
    mainMethod.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "org/python/util/PythonInterpreter", "setOut", "(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)V");
    mainMethod.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "err", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
    mainMethod.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "org/python/util/PythonInterpreter", "setErr", "(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)V");

    mainMethod.visitLdcInsn(mainFile);
    mainMethod.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "org/python/util/PythonInterpreter", "execFile", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    mainMethod.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);

    mainMethod.visitEnd();
    mainClass.visitEnd();

    try{
        byte[] b = mainClass.toByteArray();
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("Main.class");
        writer.write(b);
        writer.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My problem was that I didn't call visitMaxs before ending my method visit. But now I'm getting complaints about an empty stack, which seems to be what aioobe spotted.

Comment: If you're writing high-level code like this, you might find something like Javassist easier that ASM. You just make a String of some Java code and give it to Javassist to compile. Saves you having to effectively learn all the bytecode ops and manage the stacks etc, yourself. I've always views ASM as being more of a tool for, say, compiler writers.

Comment: Try to run your code with the `-noverify` flag. This should help you pin-point where the problem lies

Answer (score 2):

When you come to the `setOut` and `setErr` methods, you have only an argument, and no object to invoke the method on. (The call to `<init>` "consumed" the object it initialized!)

Same applies for the call to `execFile`. You have an argument (`mainFile`) but no object to invoke `execFile` on.

Try to add three `DUP` instructinos right after `NEW`. (To save enough references for the three method calls you want to do on that object.)